# Eclipse juno: Can't install RadRails throws error for a gem I have installed already

Tags: eclipse, ruby, rails

The thing is I installed Ubuntu 12.04, Java (for Eclipse), Eclipse, ruby, ruby gems, rails. Everything went smooth. When I tried to prepare Eclipse for ruby on rails, I installed ruby dev kit plugin. This worked, but RadRails failed with this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: org.radrails.rails-feature 0.7.2 (org.radrails.rails_feature.feature.group 0.7.2)
Missing requirement: Rails Core Plug-in 0.7.2 (org.radrails.rails.core 0.7.2) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.update.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: org.radrails.rails-feature 0.7.2 (org.radrails.rails_feature.feature.group 0.7.2)
To: org.radrails.rails.core [0.7.2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and solved it. You copy package `org.eclipse.update.core` of version `Indigo` into the folder plugin of this version. `Radrails` uses old API of `eclipse`, but `Juno` doesn't have it.
This is not a bug, as you can see here at the [official eclipse site](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/porting/removals.html&anchor=updateManager).